# Java 7 Multithread Fork Join Scheduler

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a multithreaded program using Java fork/join framework in jre 1.7. This program aims to find certain points which satisfy specified condition in all nodes of a Quadtree(each leaf node in the quadtree can be filled with unrestricted number of points, e.g, can be zero or 1000). I tested the speedup of the multithreaded program compared to a serial program on a 16-core processor machine, while the speedup only turned to be 1.3-1.5. Below is pseudo code:

```
public class QuadtreeFindMultiThread extends RecursiveTask<IntArrayList> {
private Quadtree T;
private ObjectArrayList<Node> leaf_nodes;
private ObjectArrayList<Entry> candidatePoints;
private static int POINT_THRESHOLD = 50;
private static int NODE_THRESHOLD = 1;

public QuadtreeFindMultiThread(Quadtree T) {
    this.T = T
    this.leaf_nodes = T.get_nonempty_leaf_nodes();
    this.candidatePoints = new IntArrayList();
}

private QuadtreeFindMultiThread(Quadtree T, IntArrayList leaf_nodes) {
    this.T = T;
    this.leaf_nodes = leaf_nodes; // reference copy
    this.candidatePoints = new IntArrayList();
}

private IntArrayList QuadtreeFind() {
    //...
            //...
            return candidatePoints;
}

private int getPointNum(){
    int count = 0;
    for(Node node:this.leaf_nodes){
        count += node.getAllPoints().size();
    }
    return count;
}
@Override
public IntArrayList compute() {

    if (this.getPointNum() <= POINT_THRESHOLD || this.leaf_nodes.size() <= NODE_THRESHOLD) {// trivial problem, solve by single thread
        this.candidatePoints = QuadtreeFind();

    } else {// START: divide and conquer
    // Divide Step: partition this.leaf_nodes by direction: NW, NE, SW, SE
        Partition leaf_nodes to four quadrants: leaf_nodes_NW,
                    leaf_nodes_NE,
                    leaf_nodes_SW,
                    leaf_nodes_SE



    // Conquer Step
    QuadtreeFindMultiThread thread_NW = new QuadtreeFindMultiThread(
                this.T, leaf_nodes_NW);
    QuadtreeFindMultiThread thread_NE = new QuadtreeFindMultiThread(
                this.T, leaf_nodes_NE);
            QuadtreeFindMultiThread thread_SW = new QuadtreeFindMultiThread(
                this.T, leaf_nodes_SW);
            QuadtreeJoinMultiThread thread_SE = new QuadtreeFindMultiThread(
                this.T, leaf_nodes_SE);
        // fork three new sub threads
        thread_NE.fork();
        thread_SW.fork();
        thread_SE.fork();
        this.candidatePoints.addAll(thread_NW.compute()); // main thread
        this.candidatePoints.addAll(thread_NE.join());
        this.candidatePoints.addAll(thread_SW.join());
        this.candidatePoints.addAll(thread_SE.join());

    }// END: divide and conquer
    return this.candidatePoints;
}


}
```

I am new to Java multithread programming, why this program got so bad speedup on a 16-core processor machine? I also tested this multi-threaded program on my laptop with 2 cores and 2 virtual cores, the speedup is also approximate to 1.3-1.5. The performance of multithreaded program in my laptop is even better than that in 16-core processor machine sometimes.

It seems that the default schedule policy of fork/join framefork is LIFO, how could I changed to FIFO?

By the way, I found that processing some leaf nodes which have many points takes up much processing time. Could I modify the fork/join scheduler such that it processes the nodes with a large number of points first? Thus it should obtain a better performance. 
Thanks!

Comment: More nodes increases overhead.  You want to have as few nodes as will utilise all the CPUs.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So increase the POINT_THRESHOLD and NODE_THRESHOLD to increase thread granularity? But I thought the poor performance may due to coarse granularity...If we increase granularity, then more points will be processed by that thread, the processing time of the thread is super-linear to the number of points in the leaf nodes. Thus coarse granularity may increase processing time.

Comment: If you have 16 CPU you need at least 16-64 threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much documentation for this framework. It certainly is easy to misunderstand the purpose. This framework is for the recursive decomposition of balanced trees (DAG.) It doesn't tolerate misuse very well since it was originally designed as an experiment in a research paper.

The framework wants to split left, right. Left.fork(), right.compute(), left.join(). This way it walks down the leaves of a balanced tree. Forked tasks go back into its deque hopefully stolen by other threads. When all goes as planned each thread forks enough tasks for other threads and is kept busy.

What you are doing is putting three tasks back into the deque and then processing one quad. This doesn't spread the work around very well. What you can end up with is several threads having many tasks pending instead of many threads having few pending tasks. This framework is incapable of load balancing properly.

There is also the problem of join(). Join() requires a context switch to free the thread for other work. This framework cannot do a context switch so it creates a “continuation thread” for each join() and then issues a wait() for the joining thread. With many joins, you may have a lot of create/destroy overhead. The Java8 version does away with the “continuation thread” but ends up stalling frequently (especially the way you are doing it.)

Try redesigning to process a DAG and see what happens. With 16 threads it should work well.

Comment: Hi, edharned, thanks for this answer. I have several questions: 1. How to implement several threads having many pending tasks? Could you give a concrete code example? :) As I know, the fork/join framework uses default LIFO schedule policy, which greatly reduces the number of active threads compared to FIFO schedule policy; 2. Why partition into three subtasks in each recursive step results in an unbalanced tree, while binary partition results in a balanced tree? As far as I am concerned, Balance or not should related to DOC_THRESHOLD and NODE_THRESHOLD here...

Comment: Many questions. You need to live within the boundaries of the framework. It started out as an experiment for a research paper, not a commercial application development package. Threads have to wake up and go looking for work so there is no way to balance the load. In a tree, you half, fork/compute, which gives other threads a chance to pick up the forked task and do the same. Every thread is doing one split up to the threshold. This gives the other threads a chance to participate. For more detail look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for any parallel problem is to balance two different problems:

On one hand we want to get the best possible load balancing by making the tasks as small as possible so that we don't have to wait on a single CPU finishing its gigantic last task while everybody else is waiting. On the other hand scheduling fine-grained tasks adds overhead so we want to make the tasks as large as possible to add as little scheduling overhead as possible.

The trick is to find a good balance between these two extremes, which is why fork/join programs generally have a threshold from which on the task is single-threadedly executed. So just as Peter in his comment observed you will want to tune your two thresholds to get the best performance.

The optimal threshold depends on many things - mostly the problem size, but different computer architectures, memory, etc. can also strongly influence it. The best way to figure this out is to make the threshold an input parameter and to run benchmarks with varying degrees.